# Php Error On Outputting DB Values

Tags: php, mysql

```
{echo "<option value="."$row3['cID']>" .$row3['prefix']." ".$row3['code']."</option>";}
```

Gives me the error:

> Syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, 
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

For some reason the editor isn't coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
echo "<option value=". $row3['cID'] . ">" .$row3['prefix']." ".$row3['code']."</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option value="."$row3['cID']>" .$row3['prefix']." ".
```

Switch the double quote and dot at the end.